# Issues with touchDragged on libgdx

Tags: java, libgdx

below is my code which I am trying to add touchDragged, I am trying to use the drag method to make an object move left and right by using the touchDragged feature.

Problem is that when i swipe on the right side of the screen be it left or right swipe the object moves right only. when i swipe on the left side be it left or right the object moves left only.

is there something I am missing?

input class and below that the object class.

also is the Tilt action same as this or is that something different?
it will be nice if that can be explained.

Input class is as

```
public class Input implements InputProcessor
{
    private Kame myKame;

    public Input(Kame kame) {

        myKame = kame;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean touchDown(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button) {
        myKame.onClick();
        return true; // Return true to say we handled the touch.
    }

    @Override
    public boolean touchUp(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button) {
        myKame.onClick();
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean touchDragged(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer) {
        myKame.onSwipe(screenX, screenY, pointer);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean mouseMoved(int screenX, int screenY) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean scrolled(int amount) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

and Kame class is as :

```
    public class Kame 
    {
  private Vector2 position;
  private Vector2 velocity;
  private Vector2 acceleration;

private int width;
private int height;
public float x;

public Kame(float x, float y, int width, int height) {
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
    position = new Vector2(x, y);
    velocity = new Vector2(0, 0);
    acceleration = new Vector2(0, 460);
}

public void update(float delta) {

}

public boolean onSwipe(int velocityX, int velocityY, int delta) {

    position.add(position.cpy().scl(delta));

    // if (Math.abs(velocityX) < Math.abs(velocityY)) {
        if (velocityX > 136) {
            position.x += 3;//x cordinate
            velocity.y += 10;
        } else if (velocityX < 136) {
            position.x -= 3;
            velocity.y += 10;
        } else {
            // Do nothing.
        }
    // } else {
        // Ignore the input, because we don't care about up/down swipes.
    // }
    return true;
}

public float getX() {
    return position.x;
}

public float getY() {
    return position.y;
}

public float getWidth() {
    return width;
}

public float getHeight() {
    return height;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change the code from

```
@Override
public boolean touchDragged(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer) {
myKame.onSwipe(screenX, screenY, pointer);
return true;
}

@Override
public boolean touchDragged(int screenX, int screenY, int button) {
myKame.onSwipe(screenX, screenY, pointer);
return true;
}
```

try that

Answer (score 2):

This call to `onSwipe`:

```
@Override
public boolean touchDragged(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer) {
    myKame.onSwipe(screenX, screenY, pointer);
    return true;
}
```

does not seem to match this implementation of `onSwipe`:

```
public boolean onSwipe(int velocityX, int velocityY, int delta) {
```

There are a couple problems here.

1. The `screenX` and `screenY` parameters passed to `touchDragged` are screen coordinates.  They range between 0 and the width (or height) of the screen.  `onSwipe` says it expects a "velocity" (though the algorithm inside doesn't seem to treat it as such).
2. The `pointer` in the `touchDragged` signature is the id number of the cursor (think about using 4 fingers on a touchpad, the "pointer" identifies which finger is which).  You're using is as a 'delta'.

You can probably just compare the `screenX` to `pos.x`, and add or subtract 3 from `pos.x` depending on if `screenX` is less than or greater than `pos.x`.

Computing an actual velocity will require tracking the *change* in location (which means keep track of the previous touch location), and then scaling it by the frame rate (the `delta` passed to `render`).

Comment: Hi there i tried to change it and now it only moves right no matter which way i swipe.

Comment: public boolean onSwipe(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer) {
  
  position.add(position.cpy().scl(pointer));
  
  // if (Math.abs(velocityX) < Math.abs(velocityY)) {
   if (screenX > 0) {
    position.x += 3;//x cordinate
    velocity.y += 10;
   } else if (screenX < 0) {
    position.x -= 3;
    velocity.y += 10;
   } else {
    // Do nothing.
   }
  // } else {
   // Ignore the input, because we don't care about up/down swipes.
  // }
  return true;
 }

Comment: @Override
    public boolean touchDragged(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer) {
     myKame.onSwipe(screenX, screenY, pointer);
        return true;
    }